# R loop with multiple CSV files and grouping and joining in single file

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to import and read multiple csv files and and group them and then combine all file into single file
I have done single single file the code is given here
First I imported csv file seperately

```
`Rhodovulum_adriaticum_NCBI <- read.csv("Rhodovulum_adriaticum.csv")`
```

Than group is

```
    Rhodovulum_adriaticum<-Rhodovulum_adriaticum_NCBI%>%group_by(Protein.Name)%>% summarize(Rhodovulum_adriaticum=n()) %>% arrange(desc(Rhodovulum_adriaticum))
View(Rhodovulum_adriaticum)
```

Than listed all processed CSV file

```
Rhodo_data_list_NCBI<-list(Rhodovulum_adriaticum, ......,)
```

Than merge it into single file

```
Rhodo_merge_NCBI<-Rhodo_data_list_NCBI%>%reduce(left_join, by ="Protein.Name")
```

But I want to do with looping
Kindly help

I tried this so far

```
setwd("/Users/mdumar/Desktop/NCBI/NCBI/")


data_names<-list.files()

for(i in 1:length(data_names)) {           
  read.csv(data_names[i]), 
  data_names[i]<-data_names[i]%>%group_by(Protein.Name)%>% summarize(data_names[i]=n()) %>% arrange(desc(data_names[i]))
  Rhodo_data_list_NCBI<-list(data_names[i]),
  Rhodo_merge_NCBI<-Rhodo_data_list_NCBI%>%reduce(left_join, by ="Protein.Name")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do something like this, using `tidyverse`

1. get vector of file names, without `.csv`

```
setwd("/Users/mdumar/Desktop/NCBI/NCBI/")
fnames = str_remove(list.files(pattern=".csv"), ".csv")
```

2. Loop over these fname using `lapply()`, each time reading the csv file and then counting each `Protein.Name`, using `count()`; add a `grp` variable that holds the source filename using `mutate`. Place this list as the argument to `bind_rows()`, and then pivot_longer

```
bind_rows(lapply(fnames, function(fname) {
  read.csv(paste0(fname,".csv")) %>% 
    count(Protein.Name) %>% 
    mutate(grp = fname)
})) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Protein.Name,names_from = grp, values_from = n)
```

Let's say you had two files in your working directory, called "Rhodovulum_adriaticum.csv" and "Rhodovulum_sulfidophilum.csv", and that these looked like this:

```
structure(list(Protein.Name = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

and

```
structure(list(Protein.Name = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Then, the above code would return:

```
  Protein.Name Rhodovulum_adriaticum Rhodovulum_sulfidophilum
  <chr>                        <int>                    <int>
1 a                                2                        4
2 b                                2                        2
3 c                                2                       NA
```

Comment: Thank you @langtan, its working